# Go language time.Parse() for timestamps with no timezone

Tags: date, datetime, go

In Go I'm trying to use the [`time.Parse()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) function from the `time` package to convert a string timestamp into a `Time` object.  I know Go has an uncommon way of representing the time format your timestamps are in by providing it with an example of how their reference time (`Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`) would be displayed in your format.  I'm still having issues with errors however.  Here is an example of one of my timestamps:

```
Tue Nov 27 09:09:29 UTC 2012
```

Here is what the call I'm making looks like:

```
    t, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 22:04:05 UTC 2006", "Tue Nov 27 09:09:29 UTC 2012")
```

So basically what I've done here is try and match the formatting for day name/month name/day number, the hour/minute/second format, the string literal "UTC" and the year format.  Note that I've *increased* the hours field of the Go reference format by `7` (from `15` to `22`) to account for the fact that their timestamp is in a negative 7 timezone and all my timestamps are in a UTC timezone.

The error I get is:

```
parsing time "Tue Nov 27 09:09:29 UTC 2012" as "Mon Jan 02 22:04:05 UTC 2006": cannot parse ":09:29 UTC 2012" as "2"
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Am I misinterpreting how to use `time.Parse()` or is my use case not supported for some reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your format string should be:

```
Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 MST 2006
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Awq3TsdZT1)

That is, use `MST` for the timezone and `15` for the hour, as documented in your linked [`Parse`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use `time.UnixDate`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   t, e := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, "Tue Nov 27 09:09:29 UTC 2012")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   fmt.Println(t)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/time#UnixDate